# Passing array parameter to Kaitai Struct user defined type

Tags: kaitai-struct

I'm trying Kaitai Struct to decode some data.
I need to pass an array parameter, but ksc gives an error.
Follow is an example code:

```
meta:
  id: cat_34

seq:
  - id: test1
    type: fixed([0,1,2])

types:
  fixed:
    params:
      - id: f_size
        #no type is just an array
    seq:
      - id: val
        type: u1
        repeat: expr
        repeat-expr: f_size[1] #trying to use second value of array.
```

It gives the following error:
cat_34: /types/fixed/seq/0/repeat-expr: unable to apply operation [] to CalcBytesType

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No type (or using `type: bytes`) on param declaration yields a *byte array* type (AKA "CalcBytesType"), which not the same thing as *true array* of something.

In this case, you're encountering an error that operation `[]` was not implemented in Kaitai Struct v0.8 and lower, and that was [only fixed recently and not for all targets](https://github.com/kaitai-io/kaitai_struct/issues/633) in 0.9 unstable. Thus, one of your options would be upgrading to v0.9+.

As a workaround, you might want to insist on using true arrays - i.e. instead of passing `[0, 1, 2]`, use `[0, 1, 2].as<u1[]>`. That will work for all versions, but that will yield (1) potentially less efficient true arrays, (2) potentially unsupported array instantiation.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try your suggestion. I'm targeting python3 code, and actually, if I pass this step, what I'would need is something like [ [0,2],[1,3] ], the first elements being of an enum type at least, or a char ('F' for example) at best.

Comment: I tried your suggested solution, but I got: /seq/0: parsing expression '[0, 1, 2].as<u1[]>' failed on 1:16, expected "," | CharsWhile(Set( , n)) | "\\\n" | End. I also tried using u1[] definitions in other places of code, trying to force the array but none of them worked. I'm using v0.8, on Mac, installed with Homebrew on python3 virtualenv. Rgds.

Comment: Alas, I might be incorrect about 0.8 :( If so, then the only option left is to upgrade.